# Calling API in Parallel.ForEach sometimes returns incomplete responses

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, .net-4.6.2

*I apologize to be not able to frame the question properly:*

**Question:** Is there a possibility that the usage of `Parallel.ForEach` (used `ConcurrentBag` to add response from `ForEach`) is causing incomplete response to be sent to the calling method.

In below code: `processedRecs` is getting only **1** `Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>` in the `List` but it should get **more than 1**. This happens very rarely, but I am not able to figure out what's causing this.

I have looked into all the logs/DB calls, there were no failures in the method `SampleReq`.

```
public ResponseClass2 ManageOrders(SampleRequest request)
{
    //.
    //.
    //.
    var processedRecs = FetchOrderInfo(request);

    // here "processedRecs" are getting only 1
    // Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass> in the List
    foreach (var tp in processedRecs)
    {
        //.
        //.
        //.
        // but "SampleReq" method had processed 3, so the List<Touple....>
        // should have count 3 instead of 1.
    }
}

private List<Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>> FetchOrderInfo(
    SampleRequest request)
{
    //.
    //.
    //Processing the request... no issues here
    //.

    ConcurrentBag<Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>> tp =
        new ConcurrentBag<Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>>();

    Parallel.ForEach(arranged,
    samObj =>
    {
        var sampleResponse = TEngine.SampleReq(request.Email, samObj.Item2,
            request.pIndex)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
        tp.Add(Tuple.Create(samObj.Item1, samObj.Item2, sampleResponse));
    });

    return new List<Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>>(tp);
}

// Method "SampleReq" calls another API to get the results... we are calling this
// multiple times for different set of data and then merging this info.
public static async Task<ResponseClass> SampleReq(string email,
    SampleClass2 selectedObj, int pIndex)
{
    // These responses are getting logged and we didn't get any issues here.
}
```

Comment: Don't use Parallel.ForEach in the first place. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for in-memory CPU processing

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I'll try using normal foreach instead of Parallel.ForEach here.  (Another concern is how to replicate such issues, if it's rare how to ensure the code fix actually worked) .

Comment: You'll always have problems if you use `Parallel.ForEach` for async work. You gain nothing by this either, as each worker thread will be blocked waiting for the async operation to complete. Which .NET version are you using? In .NET 6 you can use `Parallel.ForEachAsyn` to execute multiple asynchronous operations concurrently

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: The `FetchOrderInfo` method returns a `List<Tuple<List<Sample1>, SampleClass2, ResponseClass>>`. What is the `List` that you are referring to? Is it the outer list or the inner list?

Comment: That's the outer List... List of Tuple<List<Sample1, SampleClass2,ResponseClass>>

Comment: Why do you want to run them in parallel? Did you run a profiler on a synchronous version and it turned that's the bottleneck?

Comment: I was calling them in Parallel ,since the API that is being called takes some time and depending upon the data we might have to call it 1 time or 30 times (or even more), so we tried calling them in Parallel (to avoid timeouts by upline system calling our API).
A friend suggested to try using Task.WhenAll, so 'll try that out as well.
>> To your question - I didn't run a profiler.